# Como dividir uma imagem em várias partes com link?

Tags: html, imagem

Gostaria de saber como dividir uma imagem que possa ter várias partes de maneira que eu possa definir o número de partes, e atribuir um link diferente à cada parte.

## Bônus:

Se as partes puderem assumir qualquer forma geométrica, seria ótimo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usa a tag **map** e **area** do html, como no exemplo abaixo

Bom resumindo você pode criar um shape para o link e passar as coordenadas, cada número é uma coordenada x,y.

No caso eu desenhei um quadrado passando 4 pontos, x:155,y:156, x:155, y:213, x:216, y:217, x:227, y:156.

Para adicionar outro link (dividindo a imagem em várias partes) é só colocar mais uma área com as coordenadas.

```css
img{
  border:1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2011/03/16/c7675aa8-fdba-11e2-8c7c-d4ae52e62bcc/1264abab866fd3930a8b419d21d1cff1/Chrome-logo-2011-03-16.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />>

<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="155,156,155,213,216,217,227,156" />
</map>
```

Existem alguns sites que geram o código do "mapeamento" automaticamente como esse: 
http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/

Comment: Desculpe, mas não consegui entender onde que a imagem está dividida no seu exemplo. Poderia dar um exemplo melhor?

Comment: @PauloRoberto é a tag `map`. Nela você define as regiões da imagem que serão links. O atributo `coords` da subtag `area` define a posição de cada vértice de cada área. O haykou poderia adicionar essa informação na resposta. Mas de resto, a resposta dele é a mais correta.

Comment: dei uma melhorada na resposta, vejam se dá pra entender, se nao eu explico melhor

Comment: @haykou você já tem o meu +1, mas você poderia citar no seu texto que a parte mais importante do código são as tags `map` e `area` ;)

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que você consiga fazer isso utilizando `background-image` e `background-position`, da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="link" class="img parte1"></a>
<a href="link" class="img parte2"></a>
<a href="link" class="img parte3"></a>

.img {
   display: block;
   background-image:url(/images/img.jpg);
   width:200px;  /* Tamanho das partes 200x200 */
   height:200px;
}

.parte1 {
  background-position: x y; // posicione x, y de acordo com sua necessidade 
}

.parte2 {
   background-position: x y; // posicione x, y de acordo com sua necessidade
}

.parte3 {
   background-position: x y; // posicione x, y de acordo com sua necessidade 
}
```

Segue um exemplo da técnica acima [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61ca9xg5/).

Comment: Poderia utilizar o code snippet e me mostrar como isso funcionaria? não teria que ter elementos `<img>` pra funcionar?

Comment: Isso funciona até alguma mudança no CSS ou a introdução de um novo elemento quebrarem tudo.

Comment: mais tarde eu adiciono um code snippet

Comment: @PauloRoberto adicionei um fiddle na resposta

Comment: não é por nada mas qual a diferença entre o snippet e o fiddle? :P mas tudo bem, sem problemas.

Comment: achei interessante! porém tem como fazer qualquer tipo de forma geométrica desta forma?

Comment: @PauloRoberto são ferramentas diferentes. eu prefiro utilizar o JSFiddle para fazer demonstrações. o stackoverflow tem uma ferramenta semelhante que o pessoal chama de code snippet.

Comment: @PauloRoberto isso seria uma tarefa mais complicada. não sei te dizer ao certo

Comment: é que eu gostei mais da sua solução porque utiliza meios comuns, simples, e totalmente compatíveis, para realizar a segmentação, se você conseguir me mostrar que sua solução atende formas geométricas, irei aceita-la como correta ;) mas meu +1 você já ganhou